# Can't get Editor Template to Work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying out editor templates and I can't get it work. I'm working off of [this](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2013/06/part-45-customize-display-and-edit.html) tutorial to try and get a jQuery drop calendar to appear for a `DateTime?` Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I changed my code and tested a `TextboxFor` and it worked out so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong for the editor template

`@Html.TextboxFor(x => x.Date, new{@class = datepicker}`

**Razor**

```
@model MAR.Models.LineModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date)
```

**jQuery, separate file**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            $(this).valid();   
        }
    });
}
```

**Model**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Date")]
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

**Editor Template**

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty), new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

**Folders**

[image]

**View Debugged**

[image]

Comment: Are you adding the datepicker.js script file to the page somewhere?

Comment: Yes it's bundled in. When I use  `@Html.TextboxFor(x => x.Date, new{@class = datepicker}` on the same page it works

Comment: I usually put the jquery initializer script in the same file as my template and after the html. You might be running into the script being written before the html  object is created in the dom. In that case wrap the jquery script in a $(document).ready().

Comment: I have $(document).ready() in my js I just forgot to add it above. It doesn't look like it's hitting the template since the `datepicker` class is not in the markup, sorry the picture is so small. Do I have to reference the Template anywhere that you know of?

Comment: Since you're using `DataType.Date`, shouldn't your editor template be called `Date.cshtml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `DataType.Date`, I believe your editor template should be called `Date.cshtml`. Your current setup would probably work if you omitted the `[DataType]` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much that was the key